# Can I make furniture from a video game and sell it?

Tags: united-states, copyright, licensing, liability

The video game is not centered around these furniture items, however i have made some of the items from said game and would like to sell them. everything i make is purely my measurements as there is no guide on how to make them. could i receive a cease and desist even if i don’t explicitly name the game the furniture came from or contain any logos?

Comment: Just to be clear: there is a video game which shows some furniture, for instance from a 3d model within the game. You want to make real-life versions of that furniture. Is that correct?

Comment: Comment made and location tag added according to a now deleted reply from the OP which is not visible to those without sufficient rep... "*yes they are 3d models within the game*"

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is basically copyright infringement, hence illegal. Someone designed the furniture in the game, and that design is legally protected, so you need the designer's permission to make a copy or derivative work (either in a program, or out of wood). Of course it's hard to know if the copyright owner will care, but legally speaking, you need permission of the copyright owner to do this.

Comment: The actual situation is more complicated than this: "useful articles" cannot be copyrighted, so it depends on the degree to which the furniture is a work of art rather than a useful article.

Comment: I don't think any drawing in a cartoon is a "useful article" in the relevant sense.